# unable to handle this popup used almost handler

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image]

HI.
can you suggest me how to handle this popup as i have used almost every handler to handle it but still no result? please provide some solution. the highlight is shown which is to be handled.
answer ASAP.

Comment: Can you paste your code here, so that we can see what you have tried

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate and unclear. I answered it in the linked question.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

This is the code for above image to be handled.

Comment: Will prefer if you could share code in snippet instead of Image. #All The Best #Welcome

Comment: i am putting it on answer.

Comment: //Open Browser
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
 
 //Enter the URL
   driver.get("https://www.mariatash.com/");
   
   //I Agree PopUp
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'I Agree')]")).click();
   
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.='Appointments']")).click();
   
   //after this that popup appears and then its get stop.... u can find it in image//

Comment: Sufi, it looks like you've created two accounts - one called Sufi and another called shahrukh sufiyaan. I can merge them together - which account would you like to keep? Then, you should be able to edit the existing question with the proper code instead of using pics and screenshots. thanks!

Comment: Shahrukh sufiyaan

Comment: Merge both with sufi account

Comment: @Sufi Looks like for whatever reason the merge account functionality has been removed. You'll need to kindly only use the single account in all locations. That will help you in the long term because features will be exposed as you gain reputation. Thanks!